# Devo alocar o membro da estrutura data também?

Tags: c, ponteiro, heap

Assumindo a seguinte estrutura:

```
typedef struct lnode{
    struct lnode *next;
    void *data;
    int id;
}Lnode;
```

Digamos que quero guardar um `Lnode` no *heap*:

```
Lnode *exp = malloc(sizeof(*exp));
```

Devo agora também utilizar o `malloc` para o membro data?

```
exp->data = malloc(sizeof( void*)); ???
```

ou isto já acontece automaticamente quando aloco um `Lnode`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sim, deve. Cada objeto apontado por um ponteiro precisa estar alocado em algum lugar. Até pode ser alocado na [*stack*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), mas isto é raro e não funcionaria neste caso. Então todo objeto que será apontado por uma variável, mesmo que elas esteja dentro de uma estrutura, e será colocado no [*heap*](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/3797/101), deve ter a memória alocada com `malloc()` ou algum substituto dele.

Neste caso tanto `next` quanto `data` devem ter uma alocação antes.

Como eles são ponteiros estão apontando para onde? Como você pode obter um ponteiro? Existem duas formas básicas (tem outras, claro):

- Uma é o uso do operador `&` que pega o endereço que alguma coisa. O mais comum é usar com coisas que estão na *stack*.
- A outra é o uso de um alocador como o `malloc()` que retorna um endereço (um ponteiro.

Alocação automática em C só quando for *stack*, e só para o elemento na *stack*, obviamente não para possíveis apontamentos dentro dele.

```
exp->data = malloc(sizeof(void*));
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/C/Struct/AllocOnMember.c).

Isto não funciona, ou pelo menos não faz o que você imagina. É uma flexibilidade ter o tipo `void *`, mas quando for alocar o espaço para objeto apontado por esse ponteiro, tem que saber o tamanho real deste objeto. Este caso está alocando espaço para um ponteiro, que provavelmente será 4 ou 8 bytes dependendo da arquitetura, só isto, não está alocando espaço para o dados que deveriam estar sendo armazenados.

Qual é o tamanho do objeto que vai em `data`? 50 bytes? Aloque 50 bytes. É o tamanho de 10 inteiros? aloque `10 * sizeof(int)`. E assim por diante.

Comment: Grato pela resposta!

Answer (score 0):

Quando alocas espaço para um objecto do tipo `struct lnode` estás a alocar espaço para todos os seus membros (dois ponteiros e um inteiro).

Cada um desses membros não está inicializado; ou seja, o valor de cada um dos membros não se pode usar. **Mas podes atribuir um valor a cada membro**.

```
struct lnode *exp = malloc(sizeof(*exp));
exp->next = NULL; /* OK */
exp->data = NULL; /* OK */
exp->id = 42;     /* OK */
```

Se quiseres que o membro `data` aponte para alguma coisa que já existe, podes lá meter esse endereço sem fazeres nova alocação.

```
double foobar = 3.14159;
exp->data = &foobar;
```

Se queres apontar para um objecto que ainda não existe, tens de alocar espaço para esse objecto e meter o endereço em `data`.

```
exp->data = malloc(sizeof (double));
if (!exp->data) { fprintf(stderr, "Sem memória.\n"); exit(EXIT_FAILURE); }
*(double*)exp->data = 3.14159; // evita ponteiros para void!
// ...
free(exp->data);
```

Answer (score -1):

Sim, como `data` é um ponteiro você deve alocar a memória para ele separadamente após ter alocado `Lnode`.

Quando você aloca a memória para `Lnode` será para a *estrutura*, ou seja, memória para o inteiro `id` e para dois ponteiros `next` e `data`, assim se você quiser armazenar algo nesses dois últimos terá que alocar memória para eles separadamente pois, repetindo, a alocação de `Lnode` aloca memória para seus ponteiros e não para o espaço que eles precisam para armazenar dados.

Comment: Grato pela resposta!